# expected conv2d_28_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape consisting of 3 dimensions only

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have built an image classification model but I get an error stating `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_28_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (341, 720, 3)`

I also changed the `input_shape` in `model.add` function

Here is the model I have built:

```
model = Sequential()

#3 Convolutional layers
input_shape = X.shape[1:]
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

#2 hidden layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu")) 

model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu")) 


model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

history=model.fit(X,y, batch_size=6, epochs=5, validation_split=0.1)
```

Saving the model

```
model.save_weights("model.h5")
model.save('CNN.model')
```

Predicting the output class

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("CNN.model")
image = load_img("/content/drive/My Drive/Images/Blackened/blackened-1.jpg") #image is stored here
final = img_to_array(image)
prediction = model.predict(final)
prediction = list(prediction[0])
print(CATEGORIES[prediction.index(max(prediction))])
```

When I run the final block of code I get the error mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the batch dimension which is missing in your data, even if its a single image:

```
final = img_to_array(image)
final = np.expand_dims(final, axis=0)
prediction = model.predict(final)
```

Comment: I tried this step but I am getting this error now: ```Error when checking input: expected conv2d_34_input to have shape (50, 50, 1) but got array with shape (341, 720, 3)```

Comment: You now need to reshape the input image from (341,720,3) to (50,50,1)

Comment: @GlenVeigas Not reshape but resize the image to (50, 50, 1)